# How do i sync bit-bucket repository to azure storage account .?

Tags: bitbucket, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

By this i mean , suppose when i make some changes to my project and whenever i am doing ' git push '  these changes should reflect automatically to azure via bitbucket . Any idea on how we can achieve this .

Some References i found were as follows :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git#header-3

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-microsoft-azure-900820699.html

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/continuous-integration-delivery-of-web-apps-from-atlassian-bitbucket/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reflect the changes to Azure Website, you could config the Deployment source as bitBucket from the Azure portal. More details you could refer to the screenshot. You also could refer to this [document](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37844.deploying-a-bitbucket-repo-to-azure-app-service.aspx).

[image]

If you want to sync the bit-bucket to another place such as Azure storage account,you could use the bit-bucket webhook and write code to implement the logic that you want.

[image]

**Update:**

1.You could do that with [Azure function generic webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-generic-webhook-triggered-function) .

[image]

```
 public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //according to bitbucket info to add your logic code.
        //get the commit info
        //download the resository or according to bitbucket api to get the changes
        //write to Azure storage.
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
            body = $"bitbucket info: {jsonContent}"
        });

    }
```

2.Get the Azure function url and add it to the [bitbucket webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html) as I mentioned above

[image]

3.You could use the [Azure storage SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) to write the files to the Azure storage (Write your code in the Azure function )

Comment: Hey i wanted to push my bit-bucket repository into azure storage account . By code do you mean any vs code or bitbucket pipelines i.e .yml files .

Comment: If you can help me with the pseudo code of what to write where and how to link it through storage account . It would be of great helo

Comment: I have updated the answer about where to write code or how to link to storage.

Comment: Hey  Tom , Thank you so much for such great explanation .

Comment: Just to check , How can i write sample code for these comments you have mentioned  :              
         //according to bitbucket info to add your logic code.
        //get the commit info
        //download the resository or according to bitbucket api to get the changes
        //write to Azure storage

Comment: You could have a try and if there is any question, you could post a new thread to let gloab communities help you.